# Android HttpUrlConnection doesn't support digest authentication?

Tags: java, android, caching, httpclient, httpurlconnection

- I want to use `HTTPURLConnection` to enable cache which is supported on android based on [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html)
- But when using  `HTTPURLConnection` return `401 responseCode` .

  ```
      String BASIC_AUTH = "Basic "
          + Base64.encodeToString((USER+":"+PASS).getBytes(),
                  Base64.NO_WRAP);
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

  con.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
  con.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
  con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", BASIC_AUTH);
  // Enable cache
  con.setUseCaches(true);
  con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
  // add reuqest header
  con.setRequestMethod("GET");
  int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
  Log.d("Response Code : ", responseCode + ""); // return 401
  ```
- When using apache `DefaultHttpClient` **work perfect**.

  ```
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
          new AuthScope(null, -1),
          new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USER,PASS));

  HttpResponse httpResponse;
  HttpEntity httpEntity;
  String url = apiURL.getURL();
  // request method is GET
  String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
  url += "?" + paramString;
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
  httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "text/json");
  httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
  httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
  ```
- The question how to set `Credentials` on `HTTPURLConnecion` to work like apache `DefaultHttpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

The default mechanism to set the credentials is using `Authenticator.setDefault`, but it will only work for basic authentication.

`HttpUrlConnection` on Android does not support digest yet, you therefore have to implement [RFC2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) by yourself.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35583988/395148) here for a summary on how to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Try `"user:pass"` without the spaces.

Comment: @KhaledLela Hmm, to make it really similar to the second code snippet you want `USER+":"+PASS`. I tried your fixed code snippet (spaces removed) with http ://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass and it works fine for me.

Comment: @HansKratz The problem with `digest` authentication , I think that work with `basic authentication`.