# HttpURLConnection authentication mode

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-authentication

I'm using `HttpURLConnection` class to manage HTTP connections in my Android app. Problem is, on some servers, I have a code **401** using an URL which working on a Internet navigator. I initialize connection with basic authentication, but I think these servers need an other mode. I know it works with *libCURL* and the following instruction:

```
curl_easy_setopt(pCurlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

But is there an way to doing something like that on Android? Currently, I do that:

```
...
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +  Base64.encode("username:password"));
...
```

I tried with `Authenticator` too:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

But I still have a 401 in my app. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35583988/6523232)** really helped me (but I don't use `Authenticator` class at all) and now my code do the job like that (if authentication is needed):

- Initialize my `HttpURLConnection` object with *Basic* authentication (see the first Java sample in my question's code)
- Test if I receive a code 401 and if it is, check if server was excepted for a *Digest* authentication analyzing response headers.
- Retry with a manually-built *Digest* request property (see the post I mentioned)
- And it works!

I hope this answer'll help someone!