# HttpsURLConnection Authenticator Error

Tags: java, android, authentication

I'm in trouble with Authenticator Android Method.

This method works and return 200 Code (`HTTP_OK`):

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("admin", "1234".toCharArray());
                }
            });
```

but to become dinamically i sent the user values:

```
urlConnection = new URL(params[0]);
user = params[1];
pass = params[2];
```

changed the authentication to:

```
return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass.toCharArray())
```

made a test:
user/pass: "test".

I want to receive a 401 Code (`HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED`)

when i debug and click f7/f8 sometimes i can see the 401 in response code, but i can't return it, because it seems that he enter in a loop inside:

```
httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
.....    

    httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    httpUrlConnection.connect();
    statusCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode(); //debug stop here
    httpUrlConnection.disconnect(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return statusCode;
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Server.

The authentication method it was "`Basic`".

Changed it to "`Digest`" the server tries only authenticate one time, not recursively until can log in.

**Edit**:

But pay attention, because

> `HttpUrlConnection` does not support digest as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35583988/4628993)